# How to find the min and max in a vector<double> without using min_element C++

Tags: c++, vector, double, max, min

I have a vector and it contains how many elements the user inputs. If the user inputs 4 doubles, it will have 4; etc.

I am new to C++ programming and i'm trying to figure out a way how to use a for loop by iterating each of the elements and determining what is the least and the max double in the vector. I am confused because since we don't know what the length of the vector will be, i am not sure how to approach this problem. I would like to find the max/min from the vector and what their index is.

```
vector<double> numbers;
double n;
std::cout << "Enter in numbers :";
std::getline(std::cin, n);
numbers.push_back(n);
```

Comment: `numbers.size()` gives you the length.

Comment: FYI, if you want to find both min and max elements, there's [`minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) that'll do exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size_t iMax=0,iMin=0;
for(size_t i=1; i<x.size(); ++i)
{
        if(x[iMax] < x[i])
                iMax=i;
        if(x[iMin] > x[i])
                iMin=i;
}
//iMax is index of the biggest num in the array
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::set<double>`.

```
std::set<double> numbers;

double minValue = *numbers.begin();
double maxValue = *numbers.rbegin();
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this should find the max value in your vector.

```
int max = 0;
if (!numbers.isEmpty())
    max = numbers[0]; //if its not empty, start it at the first element.
                      //this ensures that your max is never HIGHER
                      //than the largest element
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
    if(numbers[i] > max)
        max = numbers[i]; //replace the old max if the current element is higher
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an iterator of type `vector<double>::iterator`.  You can then use pointer addition of sorts to iterate through the vector until you hit vector.end() (which is located one after the last element of the vector)).

```
double max(vector<double> n)
{
     double max = n[0] ;
     vector<double>::iterator iter ;

     for(iter = n.begin() ; iter != n.end() ; iter++)
          if(*iter > max)
               max = *iter ;

     return max ;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++ 11 There's another, simpler solution:

```
double max(vector<double> n)
{
     double max = n[0] ;

     for(double i : n)
          if(i > max)
               max = i ;

     return max ;
}
```

Reference:
http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html

Comment: This assumes that there is a first element in n, which may not be the case.